# SQL Server Query grouping Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

My I/P table is T1:

```
+----+------+----+------+
| Id | v1   |v2  |v3    | 
+----+------+----+------+    
| 1  | a    |b   |c     |
| 2  | null |b   |null  |
| 3  | d    |null|null  |
| 4  | null |e   |null  |
| 5  | e    |f   |null  |
+----+------+----+------+
```

My Requirement : I have to compare one row with the others on the basis of id's.If they have all the values same or null/empty then I have to club the values of id separated by commas.

Required output:

```
+----+---------------------+
| Id |v1   |v2  |v3        | 
+----+---------------------+ 
| 1,2| a    |b   |c        |
| 3,4| d    |e   |null     |
| 5  | e    |f   |null     |
+----+---------------------+
```

Please assist.I am trying to use while loop but it is taking me very long.
I want optimize solution as I have run the statement on large record set.

Comment: As I read the question, it doesn't make sense.  How do you decide that "2" goes with "1" and not "3"?

Comment: Because the rows  values of v1, v2 , v2 for 2 and 3 are different